# What am I doing wrong; evaluating integrals?

Tags: integration

$$f(x) = \dfrac{2x}{2-3x^2}$$

$$- \dfrac{1}{3} d (2-3x^2) = 2x$$

$$ \dfrac{2x}{2-3x^2} dx = -\dfrac{1}{3} d (2-3x^2) \cdot \dfrac{1}{2-3x^2} = - \dfrac{1}{3} du \cdot u^{-1} = -\dfrac{1}{3} u^{-1} \cdot du$$

And here I'm stuck, since you can't divide by 0.. What am I doing incorrectly here? I've applied the method my book gave me perfectly as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x) = \dfrac{2x}{2-3x^2}$$

$$2-3x^2=t\implies-6x=\dfrac{dt}{dx}\implies dx=\dfrac{dt}{-6x}$$

$$\int \dfrac {2x}{2-3x^2}\,dx$$
$$\int \dfrac {2x}{t}\,\dfrac{dt}{-6x}$$
$$-\int \dfrac {1}{3t}\,dt$$
$$-\dfrac13\cdot \log t+C$$
$$-\dfrac13\cdot \log (2-3x^2)+C$$

when you have situation like this : $\int \dfrac 1x \,dx$ then don't write it as $x^{-1}$.

$\int x^n\, dx=\dfrac {x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ this is not applicable on $n=-1$.

$\int x^{-1}\, dx$ solve as $\int \dfrac 1x\, dx=\log |x|$

Comment: It doesn't really explain what I am doing wrong. I have an answer sheet myself, but I want to know what I am doing wrong

Comment: last line clears your problems

Comment: Does this problem only occurs where you have $n=-1$? Because I previously did it on $n=-\dfrac{1}{2}$ and it worked perfectly (It would be logical if it does)

Comment: yes only for n=-1,if we apply $x^n$ rule then it will give $0$ in denominator.

Answer (score 0):

All your steps are correct. But what it seems you're not aware of is that

$$\int{\frac{1}{x}}\space{dx}=\ln|x|+C$$

This is an exception to the power rule.